# generate Certificate for Sub domain using certbot

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certbot

I want generate a certificate for my sub-domain
I already have certificate for [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) I want to generate certificate for a.xyz.com
How do I generate using  cert bot

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all at once and update it.

```
certbot certonly --manual -m youremail@mail.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos -d domain.com,*.domain.com, *.sub.domain.com
```

May it helps someone